# how to run termux program on power-efficient cpu core?

Tags: android, arm, termux

my phone has an ARM big.LITTLE cpu, and i'm making a program that will run forever

```
while(1) {
    do_stuff();
    sleep_seconds(60);
}
```

and that do_stuff() function probably use so much cpu that it wakes up a performance-core every time it runs.. i want to avoid that if possible. i can theorize that giving it the lowest possible cpu priority,

```
setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, 19);
```

might do the trick, but that's just a *wild guess*, i have no idea if that actually works or not.. help?

Comment: Android really wants you to either do work or don't do anything. For normal Android apps [Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) exists to stop background processes from using the battery, and if you are a game/CPU intensive you can get [exclusive core](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/power/performance#exclusive_core) depending on Android OS version. Also be aware of process limits, see: [Termux Issue - #2366](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/2366)

Comment: Did you see: https://www.reddit.com/r/termux/comments/n3wrsu/reduce_cpu_usage/ and would `taskset` work for your use case. I'm assuming that the device is plugged in for power otherwise this could be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @MorrisonChang dang yeah taskset might work!  and no, the vast majority of the time, my phone is not connected to power, it runs on battery. it has a huge battery by phone standards though, quoting [the GSMArena review](https://www.gsmarena.com/ulefone_power_armor_13-review-2344p3.php): ```It scored an unbelievable 296-hour endurance rating, and it can last 40 hours on web browsing, 33 hours playing videos, or north of 100 hours on 3G talks.```

Comment: @MorrisonChang i think i figured it out! and taskset was indeed part of the puzzle :)

Answer (score 2):

i think i figured it out! assuming that the power-efficient cores are the cores with the lowest max frequency (i think that is always the case?), we can use

> cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq

to deduce which cores are the performance cores and which cores are the power-efficient cores, then we can use `tasket` to restrict ourselves to those cores. for example on my Mediatek Helio G95 (Ulefone Power Armor 13):

```
u0_a210@localhost:~$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
2000000
2000000
2000000
2000000
2000000
2000000
2050000
2050000
```

here the last 2 cores are the performance cores.. and thus we can use

```
taskset --pid --all-tasks 0,1,2,3,4,5 PID
```

to restrict PID to only the power-efficient cores. example implementation in PHP:

```
function restrict_to_slowest_cores(bool $print_debug_info = false): void {
        // cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
        $slowest_cores = [ ];
        $slowest_freq = INF;
        $path = "";
        for($i = 0;; ++ $i) {
                $path = "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu{$i}/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq";
                if (! file_exists ( $path )) {
                        // found the last core i hope..
                        break;
                }
                $freq = ( float ) file_get_contents ( $path );
                if ($freq < $slowest_freq) {
                        // slower than any previously checked core! trash the entire previous list.
                        // (the previous list is either empty or contain exclusively faster cores)
                        $slowest_cores = [
                                        $i
                        ];
                        $slowest_freq = $freq;
                } elseif ($freq === $slowest_freq) {
                        // this is among the slowest cores we've seen thus far, add it to the list.
                        $slowest_cores [] = $i;
                } else {
                        // this is one of the faster cores, ignore it.
                }
        }
        if ($i === 0) {
                throw new \RuntimeException ( "unable to find any cpu freq! file missing/unreadable: {$path}" );
        }
        $cmd = "taskset --pid --all-tasks " . implode ( ",", $slowest_cores ) . " " . getmypid ();
        if (! $print_debug_info) {
                $cmd .= " >/dev/null";
        }
        if ($print_debug_info) {
                var_dump ( [
                                "slowest cores" => $slowest_cores,
                                "last path" => $path,
                                "cmd" => $cmd
                ] );
        }
        $ret = null;
        passthru ( $cmd, $ret );
        if ($ret !== 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException ( "taskset failed! should return 0 but returned: {$ret} - cmd: {$cmd}" );
        }
}
restrict_to_slowest_cores (true);
```

prints:

```
u0_a210@localhost:~$ php test.php
array(3) {
  ["slowest cores"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    int(1)
    [2]=>
    int(2)
    [3]=>
    int(3)
    [4]=>
    int(4)
    [5]=>
    int(5)
  }
  ["last path"]=>
  string(53) "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq"
  ["cmd"]=>
  string(43) "taskset --pid --all-tasks 0,1,2,3,4,5 30402"
}
pid 30402's current affinity mask: ff
pid 30402's new affinity mask: 45
```

success!